# thymeleaf show top-k rows of a table

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have a table and a multiline dataset. I do not want to span all the rows of this table. So I created a counter but I get an error at the if condition:

```
<div th:if="${dataset}" th:with="counter=0">

    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <th:block th:each="t_log : ${dataset.rows}" th:with="counter=${counter} + 1">

            <tr th:if="${counter <= 5 }">
                <td th:text="${t_log.title}"/>
                <td th:if="${t_log.msg == '1'}" th:text="Online"/>
                <td th:if="${t_log.msg == '0'}" th:text="Offline"/>
            </tr>
        </th:block>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have seen an example from here:

http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Displaying-an-iterable-of-n-items-in-rows-of-3-items-with-thymeleaf-td4025738.html

But my counter does not do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Thymeleaf has a built in count property. See 6.2 of the documentation http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html also checkout section 4.9 you may need to change `<=` to `le;`

```
<div th:if="${dataset}">

    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <th:block th:each="t_log,count : ${dataset.rows}">

            <tr th:if="${count <= 5 }">
                <td th:text="${t_log.title}"/>
                <td th:if="${t_log.msg == '1'}" th:text="Online"/>
                <td th:if="${t_log.msg == '0'}" th:text="Offline"/>
            </tr>
        </th:block>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: yes as i saw if you do not add the extra iterstat, thymeleaf has a hidden status on the variable t_log, t_logStat.count does the work.

Comment: I actually prefer to use the explicit Stat variable: th:each="t_log,t_logStat : ${dataset.rows}" and th:if="${t_logStat.count} le 5".  t_logStat has all kinds of useful variables, count (starts at 1), index (starts at 0), etc.