# How to make pages on List<...> in HTML thymeleaf with SpringBoot

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have list with 40 elements, that I pass to html site like so:
(categoryId is a ID of category that I passed from another page - 1,12,3, etc.)

```
@GetMapping("show-products")
public String showProducts(@RequestParam Long categoryId, Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("productList",productRepository.findAllByCategoryId(categoryId));
    return "show-products";
}
```

show-products HTML:

```
...
<div th:each="tempProduct : ${productList)">
    <a th:href="#">Test</a>
</div>
...
```

For now it will show all elements from list, I want to have max 10 elements on each page.

How to do such thing?

Comment: If you just want to show the "top n items" in a list then there are some different approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526117/thymeleaf-get-first-3-objects) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141584/thymeleaf-show-top-k-rows-of-a-table).

Comment: (If you want to implement paging - and I may have misunderstood the question if this is what you actually want - then Thymeleaf is not really the right tool for that. Thymeleaf should be handed "the next 10 items" by the controller, each time the user want to see the next page of results.)